# drops to the top of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

i don't want to be dropped to the top of the page when i push the link, what can be the problem? here is the html:

```
<div style="clear:both;">
<a rel="/documents/templates/bilgiteknolojileri/images/cin/1.jpg"  class="image"><img src="/documents/templates/bilgiteknolojileri/images/cin/t1.jpg" class="thumb" border="0"/></a>
<a rel="/documents/templates/bilgiteknolojileri/images/cin/2.jpg" class="image"><img src="/documents/templates/bilgiteknolojileri/images/cin/t2.jpg" class="thumb" border="0"/></a>
<a rel="/documents/templates/bilgiteknolojileri/images/cin/3.jpg" class="image"><img src="/documents/templates/bilgiteknolojileri/images/cin/t3.jpg" class="thumb" border="0"/></a>
<a rel="/documents/templates/bilgiteknolojileri/images/cin/4.jpg" class="image"><img src="/documents/templates/bilgiteknolojileri/images/cin/t4.jpg" class="thumb" border="0"/></a>
<a rel="/documents/templates/bilgiteknolojileri/images/cin/5.jpg" class="image"><img src="/documents/templates/bilgiteknolojileri/images/cin/t5.jpg" class="thumb" border="0"/></a>
</div>
<div id="image"><img src="/documents/templates/bilgiteknolojileri/images/cin/1.jpg" border="0"/></div>
```

here is the javascript:

```
$(function() {
$(".image").click(function() {
var image = $(this).attr("rel");
$('#image').hide();
$('#image').fadeIn('slow');
$('#image').html('<img src="' + image + '"/>');
return false;
 });
});
```

when i push the link, the big image have to be changed, it changes, but after this it drops to top of the page... how to solve it? even tried to use anchors, didn't help, and added javascript:void(0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you use `rel` attribute instead of `href`? This way, you leave the users who don't have javascript enabled without an option to see all the pictures.

But your problem here is that your div container of the image resets to zero height each time, so the page resizes for a moment, causing jumping. It is also a good idea to wait until your new image is loaded before trying to show it.

Anyway, I would suggest such code (available at http://jsfiddle.net/4tV4E/1/):

HTML:

```
<div style="clear:both;">
<a href="http://www.bilgiteknolojileri.net/documents/templates/bilgiteknolojileri/images/cin/1.jpg"  class="image"><img src="http://www.bilgiteknolojileri.net/documents/templates/bilgiteknolojileri/images/cin/t1.jpg" class="thumb" border="0"/></a>

<a href="http://www.bilgiteknolojileri.net/documents/templates/bilgiteknolojileri/images/cin/2.jpg" class="image"><img src="http://www.bilgiteknolojileri.net/documents/templates/bilgiteknolojileri/images/cin/t2.jpg" class="thumb" border="0"/></a>

<a href="http://www.bilgiteknolojileri.net/documents/templates/bilgiteknolojileri/images/cin/3.jpg" class="image"><img src="http://www.bilgiteknolojileri.net/documents/templates/bilgiteknolojileri/images/cin/t3.jpg" class="thumb" border="0"/></a>

</div>
<div id="img_container"><img id="big_picture" src="http://www.bilgiteknolojileri.net/documents/templates/bilgiteknolojileri/images/cin/1.jpg" border="0"/></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.image').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var imagePath = $(this).attr("href");
        var newImg = new Image;
        newImg.src = imagePath;

        newImg.onload = function(){
            $('#img_container').css({
                width: newImg.width,
                height: newImg.height
            });

            $('#big_picture').hide();
            $('#big_picture').attr('src', imagePath);
            $('#big_picture').fadeIn('slow');
        };
     });
});
```

Comment: thx everything works fine! but this was not nessecery $('#img_container').css({
                width: newImg.width,
                height: newImg.height
            });

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure ( `return false` should work imo), but you can also access the `event` object:

```
$(".image").click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    var image = $(this).attr("rel");
    $('#image').hide();
    $('#image').fadeIn('slow');
    $('#image').html('<img src="' + image + '"/>');
});
```

Reference: [`preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/), [`stopPropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

**Update:** If this does not work, then it is probably because you don't set a value for the `href` attribute (I thought `preventDefault` would also prevent local jumps but maybe it does not?). Change `rel` to `href` and it should work with the code shown above.

**Update 2:** Another possibility that only requires a change in you HTML would be to add `href="#image"` to all of your links. This makes the browser jump to the `div` with ID `image`.

Comment: when change rel to a href and put prevent and stop, it goes to this image, but doesnt change inside the div

Comment: @venom: So you have changed `<a rel="/documents/..."` to `<a href="/documents/..."` **and** `$(this).attr("rel");` to `$(this).attr("href");` ? It should work. Btw. it is easier to write: `$('#image img').attr('src', image)` then setting the HTML imo.

Comment: yes, i have changed javascript as well as the html, from rel to a href

Answer (score 0):

I method I used was to add `href="#;"`. Being that the `;` anchor (usually) does not exist the scroll won't change.

Comment: @venom It should. Are you sure you aren't seeing a cached page?

Comment: specially for you ) http://www.bilgiteknolojileri.net/index.cfm?fuseaction=objects2.detail_content&cid=148 can have a look, it is not cached page

Comment: You should put the link in the question body. I'll leave this answer here because it usually works. If I figure it out for your particular case I'll add to the answer...